# How to execute a series of commands after the find command?

Tags: git, macos, shell, sed, find

I know I can write a script to do this, but there's got to be a "cool" way. LOL.

I want to make the same file changes (sed) on the same-named file in all my Git repos that are in a subdirectory. So I want to do this

```
$ cd repo1
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git checkout -b feature/issue-1234-change-url
$ find . -name application.properties | sed "s/url=https://url=https://my.oldurl-1342d3.com/my.newurl-3443493.com/g" {}+
$ cd ..
$ (do above for all subdirs)
```

But I want to do it in a single line, so I'm trying to do this...

```
$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1 | ...... | sed "s/url=http://my.oldurl-1342d3.com/my.newurl-3443493.com/g" {}+
```

I'm missing the stuff in the `...`

What's a good pipe pattern for this? Or am I just better off writing a shell script?

Comment: You're better off writing a script or a shell function. This is too much to cram onto one line.

Comment: Glad  you solved your problem below. Just a reminder that when  you use sed with the form `s/pattern/replacment/` any `/` chars that are part of your pattern or replacment need to be escaped. It is much simpler to use `s@pat@repl@` or some other char that is not in your `pat` or `repl`. For some `sed`s, you need to use `sed '\@pat@repl@` (where only the first `@` is escaped.) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, like John K advised, I ended up writing a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

db1="sandbox-123456-mariadb-1\.cw5123456\.us-east-1\.rds\.amazonaws\.com"
db2="sandbox-aurora-1.cluster-cw12345.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"

for d in */; do
  cd $d
  git checkout master
  git pull origin master
  git checkout -b feature/issue-1234-change-url
  find . -name application-sandbox.yml -exec sed -i "s/$db1/$db2/g" {} +
  cd ..
done
```